# Asking for more information about AlienVault.com using Spiceworks, viability of "suspicious IP" alert

Tags: logging, defense, software, monitoring

Website here: [alienvault.com](https://www.alienvault.com/)

I've been trying out Spiceworks for about a week, seeing what use I get out of it.  Today I log in and see an alert: "(my computer) has established a connection to suspicious IP 198.143.173.146" which apparently is some site called busedge.com and/or Singlehop, Inc. in Chicago (or spoofed there anyway).  Anyway, I clicked "View Threat Details" next to the message and was taken to Alien Vault where I was given the option to "download a full report" yada yada obviously leading into buying something.  Alienvault said that the site was actively malicious and had been the source of attacks.

netstat -f doesn't show that I'm connected to that IP, and the warning was from about 5am this morning.

My questions are: has anyone who has used this site offer their experience?  Is it useful for threat analysis and possibly blacklisting IPs etc.?  Is it a reliable source of information?

I'm in a small business network, not at home.  I'm all for paying for services that may be useful, but I wanted to check with the community here to see if they've used it for connection monitoring/threat monitoring and what they thought about it.  Also if someone has an opinion on if Spiceworks is just trying to get me to buy some stuff so they can get paid, or if suspicious IP warnings in their interface are really credible.

Comment: I have been using the Alienvault reputation services for a few weeks now and it is satisfactory. When they trigger a suspicious IP, they also provide the reason why it is suspicious. If you look at the details most probably the IP got suspicious because the fwd/reverse DNS lookup doesn't match. You can search the IP through other online IP reputation services e.g. senderbase.org to determine whether the alert is true or false positive.

Comment: However for you to investigate this matter, it is more important to determine why your machine generated the request to the particular IP address at 5am? Is there any legitimate reason? Instead of going the blacklist way, go for the whitelist and investigate anything that is not a legitimate business requirement.

Comment: I am also mystified as to why it connected at that hour when no one was here, unless the time was incorrect.  That's one thing that made me a little jumpy about it.